# Why does the node style newcommand not work in tikz-qtree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-styles, tikz-qtree, tikz-node

To reuse the labeled node style in `tikz-qtree`, I have defined
`\newcommand{\lnode}[3]{\node [label = {#1} : {$#2$}] {#3};}`.
However, `\lnode` does not work as in `\Tree [.\lnode{above}{[1,5]}{$x$} ...`.

How to fix it?

[image: qtree-node-newcommand]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\newcommand{\lnode}[3]{\node [label = {#1} : {$#2$}] {#3};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 40pt, sibling distance = 30pt,
  edge from parent/.style= {
    draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}]
  \tikzset{every node/.style = {draw, circle}}

  % \lnode works here
  \lnode{above}{[1,5]}{$x$} 

  \begin{scope}[xshift = -2.5cm]
    \Tree [.\node[label = above : {$[1,5]$}]{$x$}; 
        [.\node[label = above : {$[1,1]$}] {$y$}; ] 
        [.\node[label = above : {$[3,5]$}] {$z$}; ]
      ]
  \end{scope}

  % \lnode does not work in qtree
  % \begin{scope}[xshift = 2.5cm]
  %   \Tree [.\lnode{above}{[1,5]}{$x$}
  %           [.\lnode{above}{[1,1]}{$y$} ]
  %           [.\lnode{above}{[3,5]}{$z$} ]
  %         ]
  % \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are many possible reasons, one being that the parser really wants to see a `\node`, or expansion issues. But there is IMHO also not too much point in this, your could just define a style that does the same. You could e.g. do `l/.style n args={2}{label={#1}:{$#2$}}` and then `\Tree [.\node[l={above}{[1,5]}]{$x$};
         [.\node[l={above}{[1,1]}]{$y$}; ]
         [.\node[l={above}{[3,5]}]{$z$}; ]
          ]`.

Comment: @marmot The parser is indeed looking for an explicit `\node`. The offending code is in the `\@label` command: `\@label ->\pgfutil@ifnextchar \node {\@litlabel }{\@@label }`

Comment: @HoodChatham Thanks! You may want to write an answer since this answers the question "Why does the node style newcommand not work in tikz-qtree?". (Whether or not it is really desirable to use such new commands here is a different question, and the answer is anyway opinion based.)

Comment: @HoodChatham Would you mind writing an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tikzqtree` parser is indeed looking for an explicit \node. The offending code is in the `\@label` command: `\@label ->\pgfutil@ifnextchar \node {\@litlabel }{\@@label }` so `\pgfutil@ifnextchar\node` checks if the next token is a literal `\node` token. Any other token in that place will not be processed as a label, and gets expanded later in some strange context. The `\node` command is specifically undefined at the beginning of the `\Tree` command so instead of doing something crazy, it just throws an undefined command error.

I determined this by adding a `\tracingall` before the `\Tree` command and then analyzing the resulting log file.